# SQL Server Cursor data as result of stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, select, resultset

I have a stored procedure

```
DECLARE cursor FOR SELECT [FooData] From [FooTable];
OPEN cursor ;  
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor INTO @CurrFooData;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SELECT @CurrFooData AS FooData;
  INSERT INTO Bar (BarData) VALUES(@CurrFooData);
  FETCH NEXT FROM cursor INTO @CurrFooData;
END;
CLOSE cursor 
DEALLOCATE cursor
```

But in result I have a lot of tables, not one. How can I return one table with 'FooData' column and all '@CurrFooData' rows?

Comment: It's OK for this example, but what if column list in select statement and insert should be different?

Comment: Like it:
DECLARE cursor FOR SELECT [FooData1], [FooData2] From [FooTable];
OPEN cursor ;  
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor INTO @CurrFooData1, @CurrFooData2;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SELECT @CurrFooData1 AS FooData1, @CurrFooData2 AS FooData2;
  INSERT INTO Bar (BarData) VALUES(@CurrFooData1);
  FETCH NEXT FROM cursor INTO @CurrFooData;
END;
CLOSE cursor 
DEALLOCATE cursor

Comment: the question and answer make no sense: why are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dmitry, I think you should really try to get rid of that cursor all together. In the second example, you're selecting two fields `FooData1` and `FooData2`, but in the end, you're only ever inserting of the values....

You could rewrite that second query easily - something like:

```
INSERT INTO Bar (BarData) 
    SELECT FooData1 FROM FooTable
```

That's all that your entire cursor and everything is really doing.

Try to avoid cursors at all costs - 99% of the time, they're not needed - start to think in SETS of data - do not stick to procedural loops and cursor in SQL - that's just not a good match!

If you need to output what you've just inserted, use the `OUTPUT` clause:

```
INSERT INTO Bar (BarData) 
    OUTPUT Inserted.* 
    SELECT FooData1 FROM FooTable
```

Comment: I need to return data from stored procedure ("SELECT @CurrFooData1 AS FooData1, @CurrFooData2 AS FooData2" does it).
But "INSERT INTO .. SELECT.." doesn't return any data.

Comment: @Dmitry: updated my answer - use the `OUTPUT` clause to re-output what you've just inserted

Answer (score 1):

Is it that you want to output the data you just inserted? If that is the case, and if you are using a version of SQL Server **prior** to SQL Server 2005, then you can stuff the values you want into a temp table like so:

```
Create Table #FooTemp ( FooData ... )

Insert #FooTemp( FooData )
Select FooData
From FooTable

Insert Bar( BarData )
Select FooData
From #FooTemp

Select FooData
From #FooTemp
```

The downside to this approach is that it will likely cause a recompile on your stored procedure each time it is run because of the temp table.

If you are using SQL Server 2000+ you could do the same as above only in a table variable:

```
Declare @FooTemp Table ( FooData ... )

Insert @FooTemp( FooData )
Select FooData
From FooTable

Insert Bar( BarData )
Select FooData
From @FooTemp

Select FooData
From @FooTemp
```

If you are using SQL Server 2005+, you can use the OUTPUT clause like so:

```
Insert Bar( BarData )
 OUTPUT inserted.BarData
Select FooData
From FooTable
```